# Show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

$$G = \left\{ 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & 1  \\
  \end{pmatrix}
\text{with $a$ in $\{1, -1\}$ and $b$ in } \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

G is a subgroup of the matrix group $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$. Show that $\phi : G \rightarrow \{1,-1\} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ given by $ (
 \begin{smallmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & 1  \\
  \end{smallmatrix})
\rightarrow (a,\overline{b})$ is a homomorphism.

So we have to show that $\phi(xy) = \phi(x) \phi(y)$.

I chose two random matrices in G with top entries a,b and c,d and ended up with $(ac, \overline{ad+b})$. Now I have to show that $(ac, \overline{ad+b})$ equals $(a,\overline{b})(c,\overline{d})$. Can I rewrite the latter as $(ac,\overline{bd})$? And if so, can $\overline{ad+b}=\overline{bd}$ be correct? Because if b is even and d is uneven I believe $\overline{ad+b}=\overline{1}$ and $\overline{bd}=\overline{0}$.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is additive not multiplicative. So, $a\in\{-1,1\}$ is always equal to $1$.

Comment: Yes, Z/2Z under multiplication is not a group.  {1,-1} under multiplication and Z/2Z under addition.  (ac, ad + b) = (ac, d + b).

Comment: When you use \text{} in the expression $\text{“with a in {1,-1} and b in }\mathbb Z\text{''}$ then not only are $a$ and $b$ not italicized but you see a hyphen where there should be a minus sign.  I changed it to $\text{“with $a$ in $\{1,-1\}$ and $b$ in }\mathbb Z\text{''}$.  Notice the conspicuous difference between the hyphen and the minus sign.  Notice also this: $$ a\text{-}b\quad\text{versus}\quad a-b $$ (First a hyphen, then a minus sign.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is better if you denote the operation in $\{1,-1\}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as $(a,\overline{b})*(c,\overline{d})=(ac,\overline{b}+\overline{d})$, because the usual operation in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is addition.

Written in this fashion, you will get that if $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}c & d\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}$ then $$\phi(AB)=\phi\left(\begin{bmatrix}ac&ad+b\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)=(ac,\overline{ad+b})=(ac,\overline{a}\overline{d}+\overline{b})$$ and $\phi(A)*\phi(B)=(a,\overline{b})*(c,\overline{d})=(ac,\overline{b}+\overline{d})$

The last components are equal because for both $a=1,-1$ we have $\overline{a}=\overline{1}$.

Comment: I just assumed $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{z}$ was a group under multiplication even though it's always stated explicitly if that's the case. It all makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin: in fact, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is never a group under multiplication - the equivalence class of $0$ is never invertible.